# Calculating max total over a period of time where values are increase and decrease

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, numpy

I have a situation where I need to calculate the total number of clients for a day from a DataFrame where the values increase and decrease. But here is the catch:

If I have a Dataframe like so

```
DATETIME                CLIENTS
2018-03-03 08:00:00     1
2018-03-03 09:00:00     2
2018-03-03 10:00:00     3
2018-03-03 11:00:00     4
2018-03-03 12:00:00     5
2018-03-03 13:00:00     3
2018-03-03 14:00:00     4
2018-03-03 15:00:00     5
```

The max total number of clients for this day is `7` because it rises to `5` at `12:00:00` then the value decreases the next hour BUT we do not subtract from `5` and then it rises to `4` at `14:00:00` so we ADD `1` and `5` at `15:00:00` so we ADD another `1` so in total there are `7` max clients throughout the day.

I have tried cumsum() and MAX() as thought these would be useful but alas...

I need to implement this either in SQL or Python. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Huh?  Why isn't the answer "7"?  What if the second total rose to only 4?  Or to 7?  Or if it decreased and peaked three times?  Your explanation does not explain the logic fully.

Comment: isn't  7 customers in total? at 13.00 2 left and later 2 arrives...

Comment: Apologies! You are both correct! I shall edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is that you only want to count the coming-in visitors, not the leaving ones. Now, if you take `diff()`, then those coming-in are positive and leaving are negative. So we can just mask the negative with `0` and sum again.

Let's try:

```
dates = df.DATETIME.dt.normalize()

max_visitors = (df.groupby(dates)['CLIENTS'].diff()  # find the difference
                  .fillna(df['CLIENTS'])             # these are the first records in the day
                  .clip(0)                           # replace negatives with 0
                  .groupby(dates).sum()              # sum by days
               )
```

Output:

```
DATETIME
2018-03-03    7.0
Name: CLIENTS, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ then you can use `LAG()` window function and aggregation:

```
select
  sum(case when clients > prev then clients - prev end) total
from (
  select *, lag(clients, 1, 0) over (order by datetime) prev
  from tablename
  where date(datetime) = '2018-03-03'
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dae25192281e30394655c4b1dd2f0b45).

Comment: Plus 1 as I m sure it will help someone but as I am not using MySql 8.0+ I cannot use this solution :)